# Choice of drawing and animation technique for an animated music staff

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm working on an app where I must have on a part of the screen an animated music staff. That's:

- 5 static lines
- A dozen of music notes (each one is basically an oval and a line)
- A few additional symbols (clefs)

I must have a precise control of the size of each element, and have to smoothly animate position and alpha of the notes and clefs so the notes are moving right to left (disappearing when on the left of the screen, and appearing when on the right, hence the alpha). I also have to change sometimes the color of the notes.

I think I can't use standard "Animations" class, as it's an endless animation with the speed and the notes depending on real time factors.

So what is/are the best way(s) to do that and to achieve a smooth animation?

Different Views? (VectorDrawables?) Single SurfaceView where I manually draw each shape at each frame? (or TextureView?)

(Note: minimum API is set to 15)

Thank you for helping me choosing the right technique.

Answer (score 0):

So you're wrong about the Animations class being infinite.  It doesn't need to be.  However EVERYTHING in Android will depend on real life factors-  Android is not a RTOS (real time OS), there is no guarantee of execution time.

However, if you absolutely need total control, I would just jump to total control-  hook the Choreographer so you get a call every 1/60th of a second, and each frame invalidate your view(s) that need to change and redraw them.  If the phone is running slow for some reasons like other apps you may drop a frame or run slightly slower than 1/60th of a second, but this is as close as you can get (and what Animation classes use behind the scenes).

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not wrong about the Animations, I said the exact opposite of that: never said Animations are infinite, I said I need some kind of endless animation and so I can't use them are they are not.

Comment: And what I said about real time is that when I start the animation, I'm not being able to know what my animation will look like a few seconds after, so  I can't use these classes as I don't know how the animation will have to evolve depending in factors that I don't know in advance.

Comment: For the last part, great idea, but better to use separate views or a drawing things in a SurfaceView?

Comment: If you have a lot of things animating around a SurfaceView and OpenGL will get you better results.  But its a lot more complicated.  If your animation is a simple moving of notes down the staff with 2d objects you ought to be able to get decent performance without it, although you may want to minimize the number of views with a custom view and drawables rather than 1 view per note.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "A custom view and drawables"?

Answer (score 0):

With animators you can animate smoothly around 5 different views on average phone. So in your case (with dozen of notes and so on) it will have around 10fps. So slightly better will be SurfaceView and handdrawing all that you want. Maybe GLSurfaceView worth considering. 
In order to test this I recommend you to create some test app first, where will be 10 views flying around, and look at performance.

Comment: Thank you. But why would animators be needed? I just have to set position and alpha of the views, so a basic property set should be enough isn't it?

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear: I don't want to use an animator, my question is: is it better to use different views, invalidate them and change their position, or use a single SurfaceView (or TextureView).

Comment: @Stéphane I bet you would use something like ValueAnimator to change some value smoothly. But even if you'll just write values by hand, you can't do it often. As  Gabe Sechan mentioned before you'll stuck with Choreographer limitations. Also when you'll change some views position it can cause relayout of parent View and it'll change it's parent and so on. It'll reduce performance slightly. Also it's just really better to not use Views for constantly updating things(30 fps == many updates).

Comment: Thank you. Like I said, can't use anything like ValueAnimator because the animation speed will change during the animation and I don't know how in advance.

Comment: @Stéphane You may look at Animation Interpolators, I think, that you can change it in the process of animation. But really, with control level you need it's better do write all by hands (and SurfaceView).

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure about SurfaceView? That means no HW acceleration. Why not TextureView? Or a single custom View?

Comment: @Stéphane Significant drawback of custom View is that you need to call invalidate(), that will each time something changes, this will be done on CPU. About SurfaceView and TextureView: they both used for rendering data with GPU power and frequent canvas updating. And both have + and -. TextureView is more powerful but more memory consuming and have latency (2-3s). SurfaceView is lighter, but less powerful. So it's really depends on your requirements.